# WooCommerce sort cart items by variation addon values

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I need to sort my cart items by variation addon values.

For example I have 5 items in cart, and they have variation date:

- first item date - 2016-05-05;
- second 2016-05-08;
- third 2016-05-20 and so on.

How can I sort them in cart ? I found that all info are in `$cart_item[‘addons’]` , but don’t find solution for how to sort them.

I editing my `cart.php`

```
<?php
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product',  $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
        ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
            <td class="product-name">
                <div class="product-thumbnail">
                    <?php
                        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                            echo $thumbnail;
                        else
                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink(), $thumbnail );
                    ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="product-details">
                <div class="cart-item-details">
                    <?php
                        if ( ! $_product->is_visible() )
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        else
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $_product->get_permalink(), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        // Meta data
                        echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                        // Backorder notification
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) )
                            echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'xstore' ) . '</p>';
                    ?>
                    <span class="mobile-price">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td class="product-price">
                <?php
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td class="product-quantity">
                <?php
                    if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                        $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                    } else {
                        $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                            'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                            'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                            'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                            'min_value'   => '0'
                        ), $_product, false );
                    }

                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td class="product-subtotal">
                <?php
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="product-remove">
                <?php
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="btn remove-item" title="%s">X</a>', esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), __( 'Pašalinti produktą', 'xstore' ) ), $cart_item_key );
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
```